# What does 'storage' means in Kubernetes CRD?

Tags: kubernetes

There is a field in the CRD called 'storage'

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
spec:
      ...
      versions:
      - name: v1
        # Each version can be enabled/disabled by Served flag.
        served: true
        # One and only one version must be marked as the storage version.
        storage: true
      ...
```

What does this mean? 
All the documentation says is the above comment:

```
 One and only one version must be marked as the storage version.
```

It just doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A k8s resource (including custom resource) can have support for multiple API versions (say `v1beta1`, `v1`, etc.) at once. It's there for various reasons such as API stability and backward compatibility.

As you know, on the creation of a resource's object, the k8s store it on persistent storage such as `etcd`.     The version with `storage: true` indicates that this version should be used when persisting the resources to storage. It's inconvenient to store multiple copies of an object. That's why `One and only one version must be marked as the storage version`. On-demand of other versions with `storage: false` a conversion webhook should be used to toggle in-between versions with recommended schema changes and custom logic.

Ref:

- [custom-resource-definition-versioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/#overview)

Comment: You mean that if we have CRDv1 and CRDv2.  The latter is the storage. Then we create a resource for V1 then it will be converted to V2 then stored as V2?  I thought all the versions have its own separate lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, it will be. From the user's perspective, you will always get your desired version.